# highcharts dashboards.js does not honor colors specified in the series

Tags: highcharts, dashboard

When I put together an individual chart and specify colors for each series rather than a theme, everything works fine. As I add these charts to a Dashboard, the color specification is disregarded and default theme colors are used to render components instead. I've tried using `plotOptions.series.colorByPoint=true` but that too had no effect. Is there a way to enforce series colors in dashboards?

individual:
https://jsfiddle.net/dashirov/1dop04rt/3/
dashboard:
https://jsfiddle.net/dashirov/er15cn2y/39/

Again, highcharts-core functions as documented, highcharts-dashboards does not.

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration for Highcharts is styled mode disabled, with some styles defined in certain properties. However, in Highcharts Dashboards, styled mode is enabled, which means that CSS styling takes priority over properties.

An analogous situation arises when you enable styled mode in your first demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bsx8njg1/

Additional information on styled mode:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

To address this issue, you will need to define your series colors using CSS, such as by overriding root colors:

```
:root {
  /* Colors for data series and points */
  --highcharts-color-0: #009DCF;
  --highcharts-color-1: #BFBFBF;
  --highcharts-color-2: #FF8303;
  --highcharts-color-3: #009DCF;
  --highcharts-color-4: #BFBFBF;
  --highcharts-color-5: #FF8303;
  --highcharts-color-6: #b3597c;
  --highcharts-color-7: #b27fd6;
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xjmfLsck/

Comment: Is there a switch to disable this behavior in dashboards?

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. Yes, you can disable styledMode by setting `chartOptions.chart.styledMode` to false. However, please be aware that in some cases, it is not recommended, as it may lead to unexpected behavior. Additionally, there is a known bug affecting the colors even when styledMode is disabled, which can be found here: [#18547](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18547).
For alternative solutions and further discussion, I recommend checking out this forum thread: [#51254](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=51254)